# phpfox: how to print_r variables?

Tags: phpfox

I have that in controller:

```
$aUser = Phpfox::getUserBy('user_name');
```

How to print_r the content of $aUser (for debugging process to see the content of that object) ?

I tried print_r(aUser) in controller: NO OUTPUT

I tied {$aUser}in templates: output Array()

Answer (score 1):

In controller files, you can use:

```
d($aUser);
```

In template files, you can use:

```
{$aUser|var_dump}
```